# datetime.parseexact returns wrong month

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
a.dateFrom = DateTime.ParseExact(x, "dd/mm/yyyy", null);
```

And x has value of: 08/03/2012

However, a.dateFrom has value of 08/01/2012. Why?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use `MM` as format for month

Answer (score 5):

As ionden notes, you should have a format of

```
"dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Currently you're parsing the second part as *minutes* (as that's what `mm` means).

See the documentation for [custom date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more information. I'd also strongly encourage you to consider using the invariant culture for parsing - if you're using a custom format string, that *usually* means you don't want to treat the input in a culture-sensitive fashion at all.